# How to get all children text separated by ; in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a following problem:

I would like to get text from all children elements separated by semicolon.

See following example:

```
<div class="parent">        
  <div class="children 1"> </div>
  <div class="children 2 ">TEXT 2</div>     
  <div class="children 3 ">TEXT 3</div>
  <div class="children 4 ">TEXT 4</div>                                         
</div>
```

I know, that I can use 
`document.querySelector('.parent').textContent` 
to get *TEXT 2 TEXT 3 TEXT 4*

But I would like to get *TEXT 2;TEXT 3;TEXT 4* (note that before TEXT 2 is no semicolon because children 1 has no text)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't see you trying anything. Sad.

Comment: Keep in mind even if there is no text. A textNode is still created: https://jsfiddle.net/agyL6vbq/. This is why textContent will still return a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), you can get a HTMLCollection of the child elements to your `.parent` div. You can then use `Array.from()` on the HTMLCollection to convert each child to its text value as well as to form an array from the HTMLCollection. You can then use `.filter(Boolean)` to keep all values which are truthy (ie: non-empty strings), and then `.join(';')` to join each element in the array to a string using a semi-colon:

```js
const res = Array.from(document.querySelector('.parent').children, ({textContent}) => textContent.trim()).filter(Boolean).join(';');
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class="parent">        
  <div class="children 1"> </div>
  <div class="children 2">TEXT 2</div>     
  <div class="children 3">TEXT 3</div>
  <div class="children 4">TEXT 4</div>                                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

// Simple Solution

```
const divs = [...document.querySelector(".parent").children];

const text = divs
  .map(x => x.textContent)
  .filter(x => (x || "").trim())
  .join("'");
console.log(text);
```

// Better:

```
const divs = [...document.querySelector(".parent").children];

 const result = divs.reduce((res, cur, index) => {
  const text = cur.textContent.trim();
  if (text) {
   res += (res == "" ? text : `;${text}`);
  }
  return res;
}, "");
console.log(result);
```

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelector(".parent").children];

let text = divs
  .map(x => x.textContent)
  .filter(x => (x || "").trim())
  .join("'");
console.log(text);


text = divs.reduce((res, cur, index) => {
  const text = cur.textContent.trim();
  if (text) {
   res += (res == "" ? text : `;${text}`);
  }
  return res;
}, "");
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="parent">        
  <div class="children 1"> </div>
  <div class="children 2 ">TEXT 2</div>     
  <div class="children 3 ">TEXT 3</div>
  <div class="children 4 ">TEXT 4</div>                             
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
       let fullText = []; 
        $('.parent').children('div').each(function () {
         let childText = this.innerHTML;
          if(childText.trim().length)
          {
            fullText.push(childText);
          }
        });
        console.log(fullText.join(";"));
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">        
      <div class="children 1"> </div>
      <div class="children 2 ">TEXT 2</div>     
      <div class="children 3 ">TEXT 3</div>
      <div class="children 4 ">TEXT 4</div>  
    </div> 
    <button>Join the children text</button>
  </body>
</html>
```